# How to use webdriver mobile web on desktop browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver for functional test automation of AUT (Application Under Test). AUT is responsive web and i am almost done with different test case for desktop browser.

Now the same test cases are applicable for mobile browser as well because the AUT can be accessed from mobile browser. As it is responsive web when we open in mobile browser the UI has some different representation. So we need to run those test for mobile browsers as well. For manual testing team using safari browser's user agent feature

> Safari Browser menu - > Develop -> User Agent

and it satisfies our need for manual testing.

If we can do the similar thing with automation, i.e. running test on desktop browser with some twik, then it is also accepted to considered as mobile web automation done. My question is how can i do the same thing like modify header, while using web driver. The url is the same because there is only one web app.

My automated test are working fine on firefox using FirefoxDriver and chromeDriver. Both browser has similar development tools available but i am not able to utilise it through automation.

We are using selenium 2.53.0. Our IVY file has following dependencies related to selenium.

```
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-remote-driver" rev="2.53.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.53.0"/>
```

Can anybody provide suggestions and help that how can i run my test to achieve it and what are the related code changes i need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome provides a mechanism for emulating mobile devices when you instantiate the driver, see the full docs [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation).

Example:

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5");
Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Thank for sharing, will it also work for Firefox as well?.

Comment: The above is a chrome specific method, which emulates user agent string, screen size, scroll behavior and display density.  You might be able to emulate some of these features via add ons or editing the Firefox config, but in my experience, the above Chrome feature works much better.

Comment: For FireFox you can see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771456/how-to-automate-firefox-mobile-with-selenium/48345895#48345895