# Selenium: how to set mobile mode on Firefox Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-profile

I have worked on Selenium Firefox Driver with Java 
 
I was seach for set mobile mode. but it just Code for ChromeDriver. 
I know we will `FirefoxProfile` but i'm not clarify code on java 
 so 
**How can i setup Mobile mode for FirfoxDriver.** 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

of course most resource for chrome driver
so test it 
it worked for me

```
firefox_options.set_capability("deviceName", "iPhone")
```

and if you like to give user agent , this can help you

```
firefox_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
```

as you can see this code for python if you use java maby this link helpful for that
https://stqatools.com/selenium-desired-capability-marionette/

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
fprofile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "iPhone");
```

Or you can try what is mentioned in the other question - [How to use webdriver mobile web on desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319027/how-to-use-webdriver-mobile-web-on-desktop-browser)

Comment: Not working FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
   profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; SAMSUNG SM-G930F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36");
   FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
   opt.setCapability("firefox_profile", profile);
   setDriver(new FirefoxDriver(opt));