# How to emulate mobile devices on Firefox and IE using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm emulating mobile devices using Selenium WebDriver For Chrome, I could find from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation

Is there any way we can emulate mobile devices on Firefox and IE using Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any capability like the one in ChromeDriver to emulate mobile device in Geckodriver and InternetExplorerDriver.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771456/how-to-automate-firefox-mobile-with-selenium/48345895#48345895), I think you could try to change the user agent and browser width and height to emulate mobile device in Geckodriver.

But for InternetExplorerDriver, I think there's no way as InternetExplorerDriver has no good way to change the user agent. For more information, you could refer to [this article](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-change-user-agent-different-browsers/).