# How to open google-chrome-devtools using Selenium with Toggle Device Toolbar set to a specific device (Example: iPhone X)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-web-driver

My current code is this -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone X" } #Specifying device
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation) #For mobile
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'/Users/amigo/Documents/pet_projects/selenium/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

This opens chrome like so - Note that the `Toggle Mobile Device` tab (next to `Elements`) isn't activated, and it opens in responsive mode by default.

[image]

I intend to open it with a specific device selected, like so -

[image]

All suggestions and inputs appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I control Chromedriver open window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381324/how-can-i-control-chromedriver-open-window-size)

Comment: This is should be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319027/how-to-use-webdriver-mobile-web-on-desktop-browser

Comment: Why do you want to?